# overriding paint() and mouseEvents() of a QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt, I'm trying to highlight an item when I'm clicking it and then draw a line from its end to the current cursor position. I can either highlight it or draw the line, but not both. Here are my classes :

```
// ucPin.h 
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class ucPin : public QGraphicsLineItem{
    qreal x1, y1, x2, y2;
    bool isClicked;
    QGraphicsLineItem * li;
public : 

    ucPin (qreal x1, qreal y1, qreal x2, qreal y2, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);

    void paint ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget );
    void mousePressEvent    (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent  (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent     (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

};

// ucPin.cpp
    #include "ucPin.h"

ucPin::ucPin (qreal x1, qreal y1, qreal x2, qreal y2, QGraphicsItem *parent) : 
        QGraphicsLineItem(x1, y1, x2, y2, parent){
        this->x1 = x1; this->y1 = y1; this->x2 = x2; this->y2 = y2;
        this->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable
                | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

        isClicked = false;
        li = NULL;
    }

void ucPin::paint ( QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget )
{  

    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem newOption  (*option);
    newOption.state =QStyle::State_None;
    QGraphicsLineItem::paint(painter, &newOption, widget);

    //painter-> setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);


    if (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        QPen outline;
        outline.setColor(Qt::green);
        outline.setWidth(6);
        setPen(outline);
    }
    else{
        QPen outline; outline.setWidth(3);
        setPen(outline);
    }
}

void ucPin::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) {
    /*QPointF pos = event->pos();

    QGraphicsLineItem * li = new QGraphicsLineItem(0,0, pos.x(), pos.y(), this);*/
    isClicked = true;
}

void ucPin::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) {
    isClicked = false;
}

void ucPin::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* event) {
    if(NULL != li)  { delete li; li = NULL;}

    li = new QGraphicsLineItem(0,0, event->pos().x(), event->pos().y(), this);

}
```

I guess when implementing the mouseEvent overrides, the paint event for the selected state doesn't get called? How can one work around this?

Comment: I bet you will see what you want if you replace the code in `ucPin::mouseMoveEvent` with `this->setLine(0, 0, event->pos().x(), event->pos().y())`. Why are you creating that `li` thing anyway if you inherit the `QGraphicsLineItem`?

Comment: I would like to see the ucPin object, highlighted. It is essentialy a QGraphicsLine as you pointed out. Next, I want to draw another line and join it with the original. Hence the li..

Comment: Ok, makes sense. See if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to request the repainting of your `QGraphicsItem`, you need to call `update()` whenever the appearance changes. The `setSelected` is called in QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent, so you need to propagate it to the base class calling `QGraphicsLineItem::mousePressEvent(event)` in your overriden `mousePressEvent`. Same goes for `mouseReleaseEvent`. Or you could handle the selection state yourself, but you shouldn't unless there's a really good reason for that. Also, I think it might make sense to set your pens before calling `QGraphicsLineItem::paint(...)`.

Also, it is inefficient to allocate a new `li` every time the mouse moves - just allocate it once and use `setLine` to set the new coordinates.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The allocation is a temporary solution, until I understand how the pattern works. In the posted code example, the control never enters the if (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected) in the paint() method, not event by calling the update(). This was my initial problem and why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @MihaiGALOS Ah, ok. For the selected state to be set you need to propagate the click events to the base class. See my updated answer.